# Why can't I set the 'type' of my Asset source?

Tags: assets

When I try to add an asset source under `Admin > Settings > Assets`, I can't see the `type`-field on the 'Create a new Asset source'-page. Why not?

Comment: Is this two questions? I don't get what you want, sorry. Type settings is in settings → assets → myAssetSource (or "New source"). If this is indeed missing, please make this a bug report.

Comment: Voting to close this question for the following reasons... (1) The question title doesn't seem to match the actual question. (2) There is almost no context provided, so it's unclear exactly what you are asking.

Comment: Sorry guys, something got messed up with my question title, fixed now. Please try again.

Comment: @blairrorani thanks for correcting your post, but I think we should still let this closed. See here why: ["Should bug reports be closed as off-topic?"](http://meta.craftcms.stackexchange.com/q/3/125)

Comment: Sure. I guess if you are diagnosing this issue as a bug then yes that makes sense.

Comment: Since this question is "on hold", I'm unable to submit a formal answer. The problem you are having is with your Craft **edition**... as in, which level of Craft did you pay for: Personal, Client, or Pro? If you didn't buy **Craft Pro**, then you can't save assets to a cloud service. And since you can't save to the cloud, all of your assets will be automatically saved to a **Local Folder**. The Type menu is only shown in **Craft Pro**.

Comment: This isn't a bug report. There is a simple answer. Please unclose it.

Comment: Thanks Brandon, that's why I posted it here first instead of reporting a bug. I on bought a Client licence for development. That explains the missing field (that I viewed in a tutorial). I don't know how to 'unhold' a question and it doesn't appear to be closed @BrandonKelly. Is there anything else I need to do?

Comment: Sorry @blairrorani, there is nothing you can do to unclose it. It's in the hands of the community now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are having is with your Craft **edition**... as in, which level of Craft did you pay for: Personal, Client, or Pro? If you didn't buy **Craft Pro**, then you can't save assets to a cloud service. And since you can't save to the cloud, all of your assets will be automatically saved to a **Local Folder**. The Type menu is only shown in **Craft Pro**.